# GIT Branching based on policies in bitbucket

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket, git-branch, policy

We are using bitbucket to maintain our git repository and branches. We want to implement following branching policies . Is it possible to do this in bitbucket?? Any plugin or any code??

We want following restrictions in GIT –

1. Feature & Release branches must be created from Dev Branch
2. Hot Fix branch must be created from Master
3. Bug Fix branch must be created from  Release branch
4. Any Merge in Dev branch/Release branch should happen using Pull request only.

Answer (score 2):

You have **[branch permissions](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/)** on bitbucket:

- Limit pushes to specifics users and groups
- Prevent deletion of some branches
- Prevent history re-write

But you don't have "a branch must be created from another".

For that, you would need to define your own [repository hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html):

- either from the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/app/bitbucket/popular?category=Repository%20Hooks)
- or [written by yourself](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/stash-git-hooks-api/)

That hook would use [`git merge-base`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527287/6309) or, if BitBucket has reflogs, [`git merge-base --fork-point`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38384695/6309).